# Regex for string ending with a equal sign inside a parenthesis?

Tags: regex

Any idea how to capture *only* `para2` and `para3` in the following?

```
foo(para, para2="some string", para3="some string")
```

Comment: is "foo(para, para2="some string", para3="some string")" in string?

Comment: do you mean https://regex101.com/r/5h9h4c/1

Comment: Could "some thing" contain parentheses itself? Is there any possibility of there being more parentheses between your desired matches and the closing parenthesis of your function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match an alphanumeric term preceded by white space or a bracket and succeeded by an equals sign, all inside parentheses:

```
(?<=[\s|])\w+(?==[^()]*\))
```

"inside parentheses" is enforced by the look ahead `(?==[^()]*\))`, which is a literal `=`, then any number of non-brackets, then a closed bracket -in other words, "the next bracket character is a closed bracket".

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks very much!

Comment: I have added the following change : (?<=[\s|])\w+(?=\s*=[^()]*\)) it will also work if there are some spaces between your variable name and the equal

Comment: @Bohemian I tested your regex at https://regex101.com/ 
It seems to match the `para` parts even if the opening parenthesis is not there. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda I think you're right. For my use case, the opening parenthesis doesn't matter. I was able to use the vim equivalent to target the python default parameter with `\(\w\+\)\(=[^()]\)\@=` and add syntax highlight to it. Having omitted the first part of the answer from @Bohemian

Comment: this [Regex cheatsheet](https://remram44.github.io/regex-cheatsheet/regex.html) lists the differences of all the major regex flavors. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This one might help you,

your string,

```
var str = 'foo(para, para2="some string", para3="some string")'
```

The RegExp (here i am using Javascript methods, but this pattern could be used for any language),

```
str.match(/\w+(?==)/g) // returns => ["para2", "para3"]
```

All the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very close to what I want. It also capture the match outside the parenthesis.